# bootstrap-vue select components with filter options?

Tags: selection, bootstrap-vue

In vue project with bootstrap-vue I search how select component works
https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-select/
and do not see has it any filter options? 
If no are there some other bootstrap-vue select components/libraries with filter options?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0"
"vue": "^2.6.10"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<b-form-select>` is just a native browser `<select>` element with Bootstrap v4.x styling. So it has teh same limitations as the `<select>` element.  you will need to use `<b-dropdown>` and create a custom select style dropdown.

Comment: I am checking here https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown and do not see any filter options. Please point if it has

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a possibility.
Use b-form-datalist.
See example in the manual https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input

```
<template>
    <b-form-input list="my-list-id"></b-form-input>

    <datalist id="my-list-id">
        <option>Manual Option</option>
        <option v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
    </datalist>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          sizes: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large']
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works fine, unless you want to put custom styles to dropdown list

Answer (score 3):

**You should Try [Vue Select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select)**
Everything you wish the HTML  element could do, wrapped up into a lightweight, zero dependencies, extensible Vue component.

Vue Select is a feature rich select/dropdown/typeahead component. It provides a default template that fits most use cases for a filterable select dropdown. The component is designed to be as lightweight as possible, while maintaining high standards for accessibility, developer experience, and customization.

- Tagging Filtering / Searching
- Vuex Support
- AJAX Support
- SSR Support
- Accessible ~20kb Total / ~5kb CSS / ~15kb JS
- Select Single/Multiple
- Options Customizable with slots and SCSS variables
- Zero dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I built something for myself.  Here are the code snippets in case it helps.  I used a table because I wanted to show additional columns but it could be swapped for something else like a list of spans or buttons.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <b-form-input
                class='search-input'
                type='search'
                v-model='filterCriteria'
                v-on:click='toggleDropDown()'
                v-on:keyup.enter='selectItem()'
                :placeholder='placeholder'>
            </b-form-input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <b-collapse id='drop-down'>
                <b-table
                    no-border-collapse
                    ref='collapsibleTable'
                    responsive='sm'
                    selectable
                    select-mode='single'
                    sticky-header='200px'
                    thead-class='d-none'
                    v-model='filteredRows'
                    :fields='fields'
                    :filter='filterCriteria'
                    :items='items'
                    :sort-by.sync='sortBy'
                    :sort-desc.sync='sortDesc'
                    @row-selected='rowSelected'>
                </b-table>
            </b-collapse>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            filterCriteria: '',
            filteredRows: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleDropDown() {
            this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'drop-down')
        },
        selectItem() {
            if (this.filteredRows.length === 1) {
                this.$refs.collapsibleTable.selectRow(0)
            }
        },
        rowSelected(rowArray) {
            // No rows or 1 row can be selected
            if (rowArray.length === 1) {
                this.$emit('item-selected', rowArray[0])
                this.filterCriteria = rowArray[0][this.display]
                this.toggleDropDown()
            }
        }
    },
    props: {
        display: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        fields: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        },
        items: {
            required: true,
            type: Array
        },
        placeholder: {
            required: false,
            default: 'Select'
        },
        sortBy: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        sortDec: {
            default: false,
            required: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I realised there is a small bug in my code when you use the same item more than once on the a page/component because the id of the collapse is hard-coded.  You may want to add this code to the mounted() method and give your collapse a name/key 

mounted() {
  this.collapseKey = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
 },