# how to show a suggestion list on inputting a tag in bootstrap vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am working on a Vue Assignment. For styling I am using [BootstapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/). What I need to achieve is, whenever an user is entering a text in the input field, a filtered array that is containing the value should be displayed as dropdown. The User can either press Enter key stroke or select the value from dropdown. If the input text is not in the array, then the user should not be able to enter the value i.e. the tag might not be created. For example, whenever we are creating a question here in Stack Overflow, upon typing tags and entering or selecting from the suggestion cards. I I need similar functionality except that if the input text is not in the suggestion array, the user will not be able to create the tag

Here's what I have tried so far :

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-tags
      v-model="value"
      @input="resetInputValue()"
      tag-variant="success"
      :state="state"
    >
      <template v-slot="{ tags, inputId, placeholder, addTag, removeTag }">
        <b-input-group>
          <b-form-input
            v-model="newTag"
            list="my-list-id"
            :id="inputId"
            :placeholder="placeholder"
            :formatter="formatter"
            @keypress.enter="addTag(newTag)"
          ></b-form-input>
        </b-input-group>
        <b-form-invalid-feedback :state="state">
          Duplicate tag value cannot be added again!
        </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        <ul v-if="tags.length > 0" class="mb-0">
          <li
            v-for="tag in tags"
            :key="tag"
            :title="`Tag: ${tag}`"
            class="mt-2"
          >
            <span class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="mr-2">{{ tag }}</span>
              <b-button
                size="sm"
                variant="outline-danger"
                @click="removeTag(tag)"
              >
                remove tag
              </b-button>
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <b-form-text v-else>
          There are no tags specified. Add a new tag above.
        </b-form-text>
      </template>
    </b-form-tags>
    <datalist id="my-list-id">
      <option>Manual Option</option>
      <option v-for="(size, ind) in sizes" :key="ind">{{ size }}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newTag: "",
      value: [],
      sizes: ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "Extra Large"],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    state() {
      // Return false (invalid) if new tag is a duplicate
      return this.value.indexOf(this.newTag.trim()) > -1 ? false : null;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    resetInputValue() {
      this.newTag = "";
    },
    formatter(value) {
      if (this.sizes.includes(value)) {
        return value.toUpperCase();
      }
      return ;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How can I achieve the same? Thanks

Comment: This is not a perfect answer but it might help you with yours.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59900511/bootstrap-vue-select-components-with-filter-options/62224606#62224606

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it by using [b-form-datalist](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input) with the use of `<b-form-input>` by adding a change event to reset the input value if there is no data in the dataList as per the search value.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sizes: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large'],
    tag: null
  },
  methods: {
    checkTag(e) {
      const tagsAvailable = this.sizes.filter((item) => item === e);
      if (!tagsAvailable.length) {
        this.tag = ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.21.2/bootstrap-vue.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <b-form-input list="my-list-id" v-model="tag" v-on:change="checkTag($event)"></b-form-input>

  <datalist id="my-list-id">
    <option>Manual Option</option>
    <option v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```